# Activate 3 or more PWM signals in PIC

Tags: microcontroller, pic, pwm, xc8

I am doing a PWM with the PIC18f4550 and it managed to do it.
But only activate an output by varying the value of CCP1CON.
What I want to achieve is to have three PWM outputs and then be able to offset them to control a BLDC motor.

I attach the part of the code where I initialize the PWM:

```
public override PWM_Initialize ()
{
   PR2 = ("% # x", (_XTAL_FREQ / (PWM_freq * 4 * TMR2PRESCALE)) - 1);
   CCPR1L = 0x1F;
   TRISCbits.RC1 = 0;
   TRISCbits.RC2 = 0;
   TRISDbits.RD5 = 0;
   TRISDbits.RD6 = 0;
   TRISDbits.RD7 = 0;
   T2CON = 0x03;

   //CCP1CON = 0b01001100;
   CCP1CON = 0b11001100;

   TMR2 = 0;
   T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 1;
}
```

Attached image of the idea I have of the driver for the BLDC

[image]

Comment: So do you really not have an ECCP? You have a 28-pin device?

Comment: I have a 40-pin PIC18F4550.
You mean this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the 40-pin PIC18 then CCP1 has been replaced by the ECCP and you shouldn't have any problems.

Just enable Quad PWM mode and you will have 4 PWM channels: P1A, P1B, P1C, and P1D.

That's not entirely ideal though since for a BLDC you want 6 PWM signals since you have 6 transistors and you want to be able to control the dead-time between them.

That means that you have to forego complimentary PWM since you can't have independent control of all 6 switches for dead-time control or signal inversion which would be required if you are using NMOSFETs on both high-side and low-side.

You will probably have to PWM just high-side switches and use regular logic signals to just turn on the low-side switches during the commutation cycle with no PWM.

If you have a high-side bootstrap capacitor, this might need tweaking, especially during startup where RPM is lower so commutation cycles are longer. The reason is that the bootstrap cap needs to be constantly refreshed and therefore requires the low-side switch to turn on regularly enough to recharge the cap and you won't be able to do that regularly during a commutation cycle without complimentary PWM. The easiest thing to do is probably just to oversize your bootstrap capacitor so it can sustain the switching required throughout an entire commutation period without needing to be refreshed. After the commutation cycle is over the low-side switch for that half-bridge will get a chance to turn on during the commutation cycle for another phase so you can recharge the bootstrap cap.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
The truth is that the controller is not a limitation since it could take another.
On the other hand now I have doubts with the topic of 6 PWM signals, since I thought that I could do it in the following way.(Image in Post). Couldn't you do it this way?
If I wanted to do it the way you explain to me, with 6 PWM signals.
Which controller would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option to choose a different PIC controller, you might consider it PIC16F1786 or 1787.  Even though this is a 16F part rather than 18F, it does have a full-fledged motor controller on board. In fact, it is has **TWO** PSMC modules. PSMC1 allows for 6 discrete outputs.

If you really do need an 18F part, look for one's that contains at least one PSMC module.

Comment: The PIC18 seems suprisingly gimped in this aspect, though my understanding is the PIC18 architecture is easier to code for than the PIC16. Might only be for assembly though. dsPICs (and I think PIC24s which are dsPICs without the DSP...unsure if they also have the dsPICs motor control stuff) do this all easily

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the datasheet:
Your controller PIC18F4550 have only two CCP modules, so you could'nt use three PWM. Choose a different controller.

Comment: What controller would you recommend?

Comment: e.g. http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC18LF26-27-45-46-47-55-56-57K42-Data-Sheet-40001919E.pdf